# Can't pin point this selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div that looks like this

```
<div class="listItem jrFeatured">
```

I want it to retain all the CSS of `listItem`  but have additional CSS for `jrFeatured`

But I dont want all `jrFeatured` to be different only the one thats in `listItem`

Am I really misunderstanding this or is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.listItem {
    /* code for item(s) matching listItem class */
}

.jrFeatured {
    /* code for item(s) matching jrFeatured class */
}

.listItem.jrFeatured {
    /* code for item(s) matching BOTH listItem and jrFeatured classes */
    /* based on your question, this sounds like what you're looking for */
}
```